# Can Israeli passports be extended in Israel without a valid Teudat Zehut?

Tags: passports, israel

The [Israeli page](https://www.gov.il/en/service/application_for_biometric_passport2) on extending one’s passport in Israel says that it’s mandatory to bring ones Teudat Zehut. Is it possible to do the extension by just bringing one’s current passport if you’re not a current resident of Israel?

Comment: Where's the TZ? Have you reported it lost or stolen, if it was? If not - why can't you bring it? Carrying TZ is mandatory in Israel at all times.

Comment: @littleadv it's been expired for over a decade, so I don't think it's of any use?

Comment: @littleadv Wiki claims that "since 2005, the law also permits the use of a valid driver's license or a valid Israeli passport"

Comment: Bring it with you and get a new one while at it then. Your person won't have a valid passport when they leave the appointment, and if they haven't renewed the TZ, I suspect their Israeli driver license is also very much expired?

Comment: @littleadv yes, that's true... But wouldn't one need a valid TZ at the passport renewal appointment, assuming it's mandatory?

Comment: Does it say "valid" on that page? TZ also has 10 years validity as the passport, and many folks issue them together. So if your passport is expired - your TZ will be as well. Sounds like a pretty trivial scenario.

Comment: @littleadv unclear. It says "ID card (your driving license won't be accepted), Israeli passport if you have one (even if it's not valid)". So the passport doesn't have to be valid but TZ may or may not have to be.

Comment: Bring it, expired or not, get it renewed as well while at it. Will get a biometric one instead of the old style laminated paper - those should be replaced anyway. They may want to check that he has some other unexpired ID (although seems like all the Israeli documents are expired - bring foreign documents as well, whatever they have)

Comment: @littleadv that's a valid strategy normally but currently passport appointments are scarce (closest one in the whole country is for January) so if they demand a second visit after a valid TZ has been issued, it would be better to arrive to the country a couple weeks earlier. I'll email their office and will post an answer if no one else does.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference that would clarify your question, and I don't know of anyone with any personal experience in such a situation. So yes, try to call them and ask. Maybe someone else will answer. I understand how this can all be stressful, dealing with bureaucracy, especially when need to include some international travel, is stressful.

Comment: @JonathanReez, they will not ask for a new appointment. In addition, the process for ID and a Passport is the same, the difference is only what you order. Take note that since you don't have a permanent address in Israel you will need to come again to collect your new ID. Not sure if you can ask to collect it in another office or only in the same office where you issued it.